# How to make a circuit that generates 50mA current at +1.8v within 10ns rise time?

Tags: power, current, avr, atmega, time

I am using Atmega328 MCU to control a SRAM IC and it is required to power up the IC using a source that can deliver 50mA current at +1.8v within 10ns rise time without any voltage drop. unfortunately my MCU can't provide this much current with such rising time. So I need an external circuit that can be controlled by my MCU which have these capabilities.

---

It's a [PUF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_unclonable_function) based SRAM IC, we fabricated it. It's not a commercial IC.

The idea is based on whenever we power the SRAM cell it will give us the initial bit stored in the SRAM, and this bit is always the same. This bit is different from one cell to another and is based on the fabrication variation. So we need a very fast source to power up the SRAM, if it's not fast enough we could get the wrong bit.

Comment: What SRAM IC is it? That sounds very strange.

Comment: What I wanted to know was *how* you know it needs 50mA within 10nS? (I was hoping for a datasheet I could take a look at). Does it behave strangely or something if the power isn't applied fast enough?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, SRAM is a volatile memory, it loses it's state when powered off, and will have a random state when powered up (but usually you'd initialise the memory to set it to whatever you want after it's powered up). I don't understand what difference a slower rise time would have, why is the initial power up state important? If you need a specific bit pattern at power up, then either make the SRAM latches slightly asymmetric so they *always* start in the same state or just use flash memory instead...

Comment: Could you use a RF BJT as a high side switch to gate power to  your IC? Like a BLT81 perhaps?

Comment: @tom : No when we power the SRAM it will not have a random state, it will always give us the same bit every time, and that's how PUF SRAM works. and I can't use thing else since the IC has already been fabricated :)  I appreciate your help, but the main question here is how to generate such trigger not how to use a different type of RAM.

Comment: Wouldn'ta simple high side bjt of MOSFET do the job?

Comment: 100ns rise time barely calls for a 200MHz bandwidth - there's a lot of transistors that will do that. As mentioned, RF transistors are a good bet, but look at the datasheet of any smaller MOSFET and you should find rise times in that order of magnitude, given that the gate was driven by a capable current source

Comment: In your question you say you need to power up the RAM but the MCU cannot provide that. Why do you need to power the RAM through the MCU?

Comment: Didn't you think at all about this issue *before* you fabbed the chip?

Comment: @user110971: because I am testing the IC using the MCU !! there are other signals that the SRAM need in order to read the data from it which will be provided by the MCU. but since I can't power the SRAM using the MCU, I then need an external circuit.

Comment: @DaveTweed: even if I think of the problem before fabrication, there is nothing I can change in the fabrication or in my layout to make this problem easier.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTarief So why can't you just decouple the RAM IC with appropriate capacitors?

Comment: @user110971: I think by adding a capacitor the rising time will even increase, am I correct ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTarief No, decoupling capacitors are there to solve this exact problem. The power supply is usually slower than the requirements of modern digital ICs. The decoupling capacitors are there to provide the excess current until the power supply can ramp up. Obviously you need enough capacitance with low enough ESR to prevent the voltage dropping.

Comment: There are high current rail to rail opamps and comparators that have bandwidths high enough to give you less than 10nS rise time (>100MHz), you should be able to use one of them to do the job, the comparator will act as a high speed buffer and will trip almost instantly regardless of the slew rate of the control signal. The only potential draw back is that you may loose 0.1V or so, but if that's not an issue, high current opamps (wired as comparators) or high speed logic rigged to drive the SRAM from it's outputs may be able to achieve what you need.

Comment: I'd try a separate LDO driven from a higher rail with an enable pin.

Comment: What other voltages are available on the board?

Comment: @user110971, the OP is wanting to turn on the power rail for the SRAM in 10 ns. How would adding capacitance to the rail help? Is it possible you misread the question?

Comment: @mkeith Ok, I'm a bit confused. I thought the rise time referred to the current rise time.

Comment: 1.8V/0.05A is equivalent to 36 Ohms. I think there are video op-amps that can do this. It is similar to the impedance of a doubly-terminated line. But it might not be super easy. It would be better if the op-amp is powered from a higher voltage rather than 1.8V. (The input signal could still be 1.8V). You could also put multiple op-amps in parallel to help supply more current. Digital logic in parallel also might work, but most logic is not super fast down at 1.8V. I have some other ideas, but they are more complicated/wacky ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some analysis:

from \$ i = C \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} \$ we can determine that you constrains are equivalent to 277 pF load capacittor. If we use a MOSFET that has a \$ I_{ds,sat} = 30 mA\$ then this curve can be obtained since MOSFETs are transconductors (i.e. current sources).

Perhpas the easiest way of accomplishing this is to have a storage cap that is 20X larger - so say 0.006 uF and a PMOS switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMMFQ7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So that things you need to look out for is if the C1 has sufficiently low enough ESL and ESR to ensure that it can flow the charge fast enough. Larger capacitors may have resonant frequencies that are lower and couldn't respond fast enough. barring that then you should use a very high quality (Teflon film) cap.

I would suggest doing some sims in SPICE to ensure that you can get  the right parametric response.

Comment: This is a right way to do; however: P channel MOSFETs are slower than N channel ones. This circuit is OK, *if* the proper MOSFET is selected *and* the proper gate driver is used. The gate driver is also tricky in this case.

Comment: I suggest using N Channel MOSFET and a fast logic-level gate driver. The driver supply voltage can be 5-12 V, at least, much higher than 1.8 V. It translates the control signal from 3.3 V CMOS logic of MCU to voltages suitable for fast switching of the MOSFET.

Comment: The storage capacitor in the circuit should be MUCH larger than 6nF, since your 1.8V regulator will need output bypass capacitance. Using the usual 0.1uF ceramic capacitor should work. Using a teflon cap will likely provide no benefits.

Comment: Using a PMOS switch will almost certainly require a negative gate voltage to operate reliably when switching 1.8V.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid requiring a negative voltage rail to turn on a PFET completely, an NFET is more easily used as a pass transistor for this circuit. To ensure high-speed switching, the FET should be used with a gate driver (U1). A suitable low-side, N-channel, high-speed gate driver such as [LM5134](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5134.pdf) should be used.

At least 100nF/0.1uF of ceramic bypass capacitance should be immediately next to the load-switch FET. Multiple small size ceramic capacitors should be able to provide the current to turn on the device. No bypass should be used between the FET and the DUT and the FET should be placed as close to the power pin(s) of the DUT as possible to avoid accumulating stray capacitance. *Layout will be critical.*

A low-voltage, low-capacitance, low-threshold NFET is also required to be the switching device. Something like the [ZXMN3F30FH](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ZXMN3F30FH.pdf) is probably a good starting point. I hope using these small, surface mount devices is possible, given the investment in custom chips.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fapV3M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
(Please don't try to simulate in-browser.)